# cannot insert image in latex tex file code

Tags: graphics, include, includegraphics, wide-image

tex code

```
$\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pzt_image.jpg}$
```

Above is the code in texmaker code. The image is in same folder and the details are also correct.

in output pdf

```
pztimage[scale = 0.5]pztimage.jpg
```

lol. what am i missing in this code.

Comment: Looks like you are getting some of errors and ignoring them.  In case you are using Overleaf, there should be a tiny red square above the PDF with the errors.  What do they say?  Also, are you using the package `graphics` (with an S) or `graphicx` (with an X)?  You should use `graphicx`.

Comment: Welcime to TeX.SE :) // Why do you place your graphics in a Math-environment, i.e. in between `$  $` ?

Comment: Please also note that the rest of the settings in your document may affect this. So please provide a full but minimal example that hows this problem. As we don;t have your images, you can use the images that comes along with the `mwe` package, see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe

Comment: you need the graphicx package (presumably you got an error message?) and don't normally use math mode, so remove the `$`